# How do I display PHP array values in JS-based Google Charts?

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

The Charts documentation uses the following example:

```
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Toppings');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
    data.addRows([
      ['Cheese', 3],
      ['Onions', 1],
      ['Olives', 1],
      ['Zucchini', 1],
      ['Pepperoni', 2]
    ]);
```

I'm building my Google Chart as follows:

```
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Standing');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Students');
    data.addRows([
      [<?= $users[0]->COLLEGE; ?>, <?= $users[0]->HEADCOUNT; ?>],
    ]);
```

But no chart is being printed. How can I use the PHP array contents to populate the chart?

Comment: dont mix php and js like that, you should instead make a JSON request to populate your chart

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript

Comment: You have an extra comma after your array's closing square bracket. In PHP you are allowed to have a trailing comma after the last entry in an array, in JS it is not valid.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn This is not allowed in JSON but it is in JS

Comment: Okay, with that comma fixed, it's still not rendering, even after doing json_encode() on the values.

Comment: @Aragon0 JSON *is* JS. Swing and a miss.

Comment: @KinsDotNet read this https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example

Comment: @sudowned JSON.parse produces an error but at least V8 and Gecko process objects in the javascript code with a comma at the end fine.

Comment: @Aragon0 Web browsers are notoriously lax in implementation. A browser looking past syntax errors in order to Just Work is not surprising, and does not by nature reflect the language specification.

Comment: Okay, @meda,
Aragon's answer below, with the JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK option did the trick. Is this a sufficient conversion to JSON to cover vulnerabilities?

Comment: it works but its not the proper way of achieving this, basically this is like building javascript with PHP

Comment: @meda I would like to do it the proper way, can you provide a code example the way that Aragorn0 did?

I read through the link you provided and it's not really specific enough to my case to really apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't add quotes to the resulting JavaScript values (and you don't escape them). PHPs json_encode has the ability to produce valid JavaScript values from PHP strings and handle all the quotes and escaping for you so just use that:

```
 var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Standing');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Students');
    data.addRows([
      [<?= json_encode($users[0]->COLLEGE); ?>, <?= json_encode($users[0]->HEADCOUNT, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>],
    ]);
```

That should also prevent a whole bunch of XSS and other nasty code injection attacks and handle escaping.

Comment: I saw that, but even fixed, it doesn't render the chart.

Comment: Can you show the resulting Javascript from the script? And try to run my version with the comma, you don't need to remove it.

Comment: I'm seeing "Uncaught Error: Type mismatch. Value 0.1 does not match type number in column index 1" in the console. Nothing gets displayed on the page at all

Comment: https://gist.github.com/pnc89/dfd7581ec6d825c25ecd

It looks like the data is output properly, but I'm clueless as to why it's not building the chart still.

Comment: It's because json_encode is displaying it as a string with quotation marks. How might I fix that?